# How to create an empty column

Tags: r

I have to consider three columns of a dataset.
One of them has values from 1 to 10, while the others have values from 2 to 10. I wanted to sum the frequencies for each value for all the three columns but an error appears, I think because two columns don't have values for 1.
How can I solve it?

This is what I have:

```
                take.care
face_prod         2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
  anti-age        0  1  0  5  3  8  4  1  3
  Hydrating       2  3  1  8  9 14  9  3  9
  normal skin     0  0  0  0  4  0  1  0  1
  Other           0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0
  purifying       0  0  1  1  4  7  8  4  5
  sensitive skin  0  0  0  0  1  2  0  0  1
                look.fundam
face_prod         2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
  anti-age        0  0  0  2  2  4  3  5  9
  Hydrating       1  0  1  4 12  7 10  5 18
  normal skin     0  0  0  0  1  2  1  1  1
  Other           0  1  0  0  2  0  0  0  0
  purifying       0  1  0  0  3  5  9  3  9
  sensitive skin  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
                good.app
face_prod         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
  anti-age        0  1  1  3  5  2  3  6  1  3
  Hydrating       4  1  5  5  8  9 10  7  4  5
  normal skin     0  0  0  0  2  2  1  0  0  1
  Other           2  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  purifying       2  0  1  2  3  4  7  5  5  1
  sensitive skin  1  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  1
```

It's not a dataset but the result of the table() function

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

If there are some levels missing, an option is to standardize with `factor` and `levels` specified as 1 to 10

```
nm1 <- c('take.care', 'look.fundam', 'good.app')
df1[nm1] <- lapply(df1[nm1], factor, levels = 1:10)
```

and now use the `table`